# merge two mathematical tables and find the kth element

Tags: math

merge multiples of two numbers and find the kth element from starting.for instance,

```
multiples of 3 are 3,6,9,12...
multiples of 5 are 5,10,15,20...
```

so finally after merging these two array of numbers we get an array as
`3,5,6,9,10,12,15,15,18,20`
    therefore:

```
the 5th element is 10
the 9th element is 18
```

NOTE: if a number occurs twice (15 in the above case) consider it as 2 different events. 
    let a be the first number,b the second number then k be the element need to be found in the merge of the multiples of a and b.then derive a generalised formula
    for finding the kth element.
    example:
        a=3
        b=5
        k=5
        ans:10
        a=3
        b=5
        k=9
        ans:18

Answer (score 0):

If you take *b* steps in the sequence for *a*, and *a* steps in the sequence for *b*, then you will arrive at the common element *a⋅b*. So for *k*=*a*+*b* the answer is *m*=*ab*. For *k*=2(*a*+*b*) you get *m*=2⋅*ab* as the answer. Therefore a first approximation would be *m*=*k*⋅*ab*/(*a*+*b*). But this will usually be incorrect if *k* is not a multiple of *a*+*b*.

So take

```
m0 = (k * a * b) / (a + b)
```

as a first approximation. Round that to a multiple of *a* resp. *b*. Since the values of `m0` look too small, let's start by rounding them up to `mA` which is a multiple of *a* and to `mB` which is a multiple of *b*.

```
k   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
m   3     5     6     9    10    12    15    15    18    20    21    24
m0  1.88  3.75  5.62  7.50  9.38 11.25 13.12 15.00 16.88 18.75 20.62 22.50 
mA  3     6     6     9    12    12    15    15    18    21    21    24
mB  5     5    10    10    15    15    15    20    20    25    25    27
```

Not good enough yet. In some cases, the right value *m* isn't even one of `mA` or `mB`. For *k*=10 for example, both values are too big. So how about rounding down instead of up?

```
k   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
m   3     5     6     9    10    12    15    15    18    20    21    24
m0  1.88  3.75  5.62  7.50  9.38 11.25 13.12 15.00 16.88 18.75 20.62 22.50 
ma  0     3     3     6     9     9    12    15    15    18    18    21
mb  0     0     5     5     5    10    10    15    15    15    20    20
m1  0     3     5     6     9    10    12    15    15    18    20    21
```

At first glance, this doesn't look much better. But if you look at the last row, `m1 = max(ma, mb)`, then you may notice that it is like *m* just shifted by one. Which leads us to the final solution:

```
m = max(floor((k + 1) * b / (a + b)) * a,
        floor((k + 1) * a / (a + b)) * b)
```

I tried this approach with many different inputs, and so far it seems to work. That's no mathematical proof, but good enough for me today.